# Очень простая задачка (c++)

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Имеется очень простая задачка, не могу додумать последнее условие N=A.

Задачка:

> Вы покупаете смартфон в магазине с гибкой системой скидок. Если исходная стоимость смартфона больше A рублей, на неё устанавливается скидка в X процентов. Если исходная стоимость смартфона больше B рублей, скидка составит Y процентов. На вход программе даны пять вещественных чисел: N, A, B, X, Y. N — исходная стоимость товара. Число A меньше числа B. Выведите стоимость покупки смартфона с учётом скидки.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double n, a, b, x, y;
    cin >> n >> a >> b >> x >> y;
    if (n > b) {
        cout << n - ((n * y) / 100) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (n > a) {
        cout << n - ((n * x) / 100) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (n < a) {
        cout << n << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (n = a) {
        cout << n << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Два последних `if` не нужны. Если первые два `if` прошли, то уже `n <= a` и нужно просто выводить `n`

Comment: Дайте нормальный заголовок вопросу

Answer (score 1):

Булат, ответ на твой вопрос можно найти [здесь](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/221455404).

Кроме того, оператор (return 0; ) используют один раз, а не везде где вздумается, например:

```
int main()
{
   // что-то делаем (команда)
return 0; // 0 если не хотим возвращать конкретное число или переменную.
}
```

Чтобы не делать подобных ошибок по синтаксису, читай книги по языку С и С++.

Моё решение, пусть и не самое удачное:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double n, a, b, x, y;
    // Реализуйте алгоритм расчёта итоговой стоимости здесь
    // считываем все вводимые числа
    cin >> n >> a >> b >> x >> y;
        // По заданию, Число A меньше числа B. 
    if ( a < b  ) 
    {
        // Проверяем стоимость товара, в случае совпадения применеяем скидку x %
        if (n > a && n <= b)
        {
        // рассчитываем стоимостьсо скидной
        n = n - ((n * x) / 100);
        }
        // Проверяем стоимость товара, в случае совпадения применеяем скидку у %
        else if (n > b) 
        {
         n = n - ((n * y) / 100);
        }
    }
     // Выводим результат
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: Всё для решения вопроса долнжно быть в самом вопросе, а не по ссылкам

Comment: `return 0` можно написать 0+ раз, у `main()` должен быть возвращаемый тип `int` по стандарту

Answer (score 1):

```
if (n > b) {
    n *= 1.0 - y / 100;
} else if (n > a) {
    n *= 1.0 - x / 100;
}
cout << n << endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    double n, a, b, x, y;
    cin >> n >> a >> b >> x >> y;
    if (n > b) {
        n *= 1.0 - y / 100;
    } else if (n > a) {
        n *= 1.0 - x / 100;
    }
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Поясните, чем ваш ответ отличается от [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201603)?